# MongoDB - Match all document not containing a combination of value

Tags: arrays, mongodb

Let's say I have three document structured like so :

```
{
    "_id": 1,
    "conditions": [
        ["Apple", "Orange"],
        ["Lemon"],
        ["Strawberry"]
    ]
},
{
    "_id": 2,
    "conditions": [
        ["Apple"],
        ["Strawberry"]
    ]
},
{
    "_id": 3,
    "conditions": [
        ["Apple", "Lime"]
    ]
}
```

And I have an array, I'll call it ARC for this example :

```
ARC = [
    "Apple",
    "Lime",
    "Banana",
    "Avocado",
    "Cherry"
]
```

I would like to return all document in which all conditions subarray values can't be found in the ARC array.

For example, with the data above, the first document **should** be returned because :

- The Apple AND Orange combination is not in the ARC array
- Lemon is not in the ARC array
- Strawberry is not in the ARC array

The second document **shouldn't** be returned because :

- Apple is in the ARC array

And the third document **shouldn't** be returned because :

- The Apple AND Lime combination is in the ARC array

I've tried

```
db.example.find({"conditions": {$not: {$elemMatch: {$all: [ARC]}}}})
```

But it seems way too simple.. So, as expected, it doesn't work.

I know mongoDB is pretty powerful with all the aggregation and stuff but I'm a bit lost.

Do you know if it's possible with a query alone and if so, what should I look for ?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The query below should solve your problem.

```js
var ARC = [
    "Apple",
    "Lime",
    "Banana",
    "Avocado",
    "Cherry"
];

db.test.find(
  { $expr: {
    $eq: [
        { $filter: { input: "$conditions", as: "c", cond: { $setIsSubset: [ "$$c", ARC] } } },
        [ ]
    ]
  }
}
)
```

It's made up of lots of parts so I'll try to break it down a bit, The first part is `$expr` within a `find` (or can be used within a $match in an aggregation) this allows us aggregation expressions within the query. So this allows us to use a `$filter`.

The `$filter` expression allows us to filter down the arrays in the condition field to check if any are a subset of the array `ARC` passed in.

We can actually take that filter an execute it on its own using an aggregation query:

```js
db.test.aggregate([
   { $project: {
      "example" : { $filter: { input: "$conditions", as: "c", cond: { $setIsSubset: [ "$$c", ARC] } } }
} }])

{ "_id" : 1, "example" : [ ] }
{ "_id" : 2, "example" : [ [ "Apple" ] ] }
{ "_id" : 3, "example" : [ [ "Apple", "Lime" ] ] }
```

The last part of the query is the `$eq` which is taking the value that is created with the filter and then matching it against an empty array `[ ]`.

Comment: Thanks for your answer and the explanations ! Works like a charm !

Answer (score 0):

This is an aggregation approach. You should use [`$setIsSubset`](https://docs.mongodb.com/manual/reference/operator/aggregation/setIsSubset/).

Below should be helpful:

```js
db.collection.aggregate([
  {
    $match: {
      $expr: {
        $eq: [
          true,
          {
            $allElementsTrue: {
              $map: {
                input: "$conditions",
                as: "c",
                in: {
                  $not: {
                    $setIsSubset: [
                      "$$c",
                      [
                        "Apple",
                        "Lime",
                        "Banana",
                        "Avocado",
                        "Cherry"
                      ]
                    ]
                  }
                }
              }
            }
          }
        ]
      }
    }
  }
])
```

[MongoPlayGroundLink](https://mongoplayground.net/p/vFLIYMDkcdA)